# Is Master Slave concept in mysql is good for CRM Application?

Tags: php, mysql, master-slave

I'm working on a CRM application(php+Mysql), and now the performance is a main issue while number of users increase . Right now all the query is executing directly in mysql server . So Now I'm thinking on Master-slave concept of mysql, and have a doubt is that if the master is busy with insert and update then is there any chance to slow down the reading query execution from slave .
Please let me know if any other good system architecture for data handling using mysql .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master slave architecture is good for making read operation faster.

Master will handle all the insert/update/deletion.
Slave will handle only read operation.

Although slave will not slow down due to write operation at master. Because mysql use replications for syncing master and slave db severs.

In replication, binlog files transfered from master to slave. Binlogs are are binary files so execution is very fast comparing to normal queries.

Go ahead with this approach.

Cons:
Sometimes lags exist between master and slave. This may be because of network latency or slave server handling more read queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.